# unauthenticated Visualforce page through sites - https access

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, http

I have exposed a visualforce page to non-salesforce users using sites. This site is accessible using http and no login is required.
How can I make this site accessible using https ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To require secure connections, under "Setup", go to the site you would like to be accessible through https, press "Edit", then select the "Require Secure Connections (HTTPS)" checkbox.

[image]

However, regardless of this setting, the site **can** be accessed via https.

Comment: They should be *available* even without this option selected, no?

Comment: I believe you're correct there.  Edited to reflect this.

Comment: When I access it with https without the option selected, i get a message "your connection is not secure" when I say proceed anyway, it takes me back to http url

Comment: What browser are you using?  I think that's browser behavior.  I'm not seeing that with Chrome.

Comment: @apn Are you using custom domain?

Comment: I was able to resolve this. Needed to use secure.force.com in the URL and I can access it using http or https irrespective of the settings above. Production URL format will be like https://mycompany.secure.force.com